# Existence of adjunction

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, adjoint-functors

I found some references saying that a functor $G:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ admitting a left adjoint iff for any object $A\in\mathrm{Ob}~\mathcal{C}$, the functor $\mathrm{hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,G(-))$ is representable.
(like the dual https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A8B)
But when I was proving/verifying the naturality of the isomorphisms, I felt like I cannot give the naturality in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. for any morphism $k:C\to A$ in $\mathcal{C}$ we have the following commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
{\mathrm{hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,G(B))} @>{\eta_{A,B}^{-1}}>> {\mathrm{hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(F(A),B)}\\
@V{k^*}VV @VV{F(k)^*}V\\
{\mathrm{hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(C,G(B))} @>{\eta_{C,B}^{-1}}>> {\mathrm{hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(F(C),B)}
\end{CD}

And there are also some references stating more are required (like https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor#AdjointFunctorFromObjectwiseRepresentingObject). So I'm a little confused. Which one is really correct? (My personal thought was like that in nLab, in which more natuality is required.)

Comment: You have to define $F (k) $ in such a way that these diagrams commute for all $B $ at the same time. This should be doable by Yoneda.

Comment: @darijgrinberg It is easy to define it and it is not hard to prove this is a functor. The problem was how to verify the naturality, as described.

Comment: What do you see that the nLab link requires that the Stacks Project link doesn't require?

Comment: @DerekElkins The nLab theorem states another commtative diagram.

Comment: @GuanyuLi Everything after "hence" in the nLab definition is just spelling out what it means for the natural isomorphism preceding it to exist. The natural isomorphism it describes is saying exactly that $\mathsf{Hom}(L(-),d)$ is representable, namely by $R(d)$. The commutative diagram there is just the naturality condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G:\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ a functor such that for every $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the functor $X \mapsto {Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,G(X))$ is representable. This means by definition that for every $A$, there is an object $F(A)$ in $\mathcal{D}$ and an isomorphism $\eta^A_X :{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,G(X)) \to {Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F(A),X)$ which is natural in X.

So now we have to show :

1. That we have a functor $X \mapsto F(X)$
2. For a fixed $X$ in $\mathcal{D}$, $\eta^A_X$ is natural in $A$.

Let's adress the first point : to a map $f : A \to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$, Define $\tilde{F(f)}_X: {Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F(B),X) \to {Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F(A),X)$ as the composition $\eta^A_X \circ f^*_X \circ (\eta^B_X)^{-1}$. It is natural in $X$ since it is the compostion of natural transformations in $X$. Now Yoneda says this corresponds to some morhism $F(f) : F(A) \to F(B)$, and  $\tilde{F(f)}_X = F(f)^*_X$. This defines indeed a functor since for $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$,$$\tilde{F(gf)}_X = \eta^A_X \circ (gf)^*_X \circ (\eta^C_X)^{-1} = \eta^A_X \circ f^*_X \circ g^*_X\circ (\eta^C_X)^{-1} =  \eta^A_X \circ f^*_X \circ(\eta^B_X)^{-1} \circ \eta^B_X\circ g^*_X\circ (\eta^C_X)^{-1}$$
So $\tilde{F(gf)}_X = \tilde{F(f)}_X \circ \tilde{F(g)}_X$ and again by Yoneda, this gives the equality $F(gf) = F(g)\circ F(f)$. Identity is very easy again using Yoneda.

For the second point we have to show that for any $f : A\to B$, $$F(f)^*_X \circ \eta^B_X = \eta^A_X \circ f^*_X.$$
But remembering that $F(f)^*_X = \tilde{F(f)}_X = \eta^A_X \circ f^*_X \circ (\eta^B_X)^{-1}$, we get the desired equality.

Indeed we get that $G$ has a left adjoint.

Comment: I didn't see why $\tilde{F(f)}_X=F(f)_X^*$ but now I proved it. This was what I wanted.

Comment: It is the fully faithfulness of the yoneda embedding that guarantees that equality.